# Fix column width of table

Tags: tables, columns, width

I have two tables in this code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\begin{document}
\title{}
\author{}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\section{Header}

\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering 
\footnotesize 
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}} lll} 
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex]
Example & Reference \\\\[-1.8ex]
\cline{1-2}
\\[-1.8ex]
Northern Wheatears had higher reproductive success in higher vegetation height & ArltPart2007 \\ 
Mallards that avoided wetlands with large expanses of open water had higher reproductive success & BloomEtAl2013 \\ 
American Redstarts that occupied wet forest habitat in the winter raised more offspring than conspecifics occupying other habitats in the winter & NorrisEtAl2003 \\ 
Great Tits nesting in mature woodland produced larger broods than conspecifics nesting in gardens and hedgerows & RiddingtonGosler1995 \\ 
Reduction in winter stubble has led to a reduction in Reed Bunting survival rate & PeachEtAl1999 \\ 
Fledgling Ovenbird survival increased with vegetation structure & KingEtAl2006 \\ 
Daily nest survival of eight forest species was positively related to nest distance from the forest edge and nest height & NewmarkEtAl2011 \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\end{tabular}
  \caption{Examples of the effects on habitat on individual fitness.} 
  \label{table_fitness} 
\end{table} 

\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering 
\footnotesize 
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}} lll} 
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
Example & Reference \\\\[-1.8ex]
\cline{1-2}
\\[-1.8ex]
Northern Wheatears had higher reproductive success in higher\\ vegetation height & ArltPart2007 \\ 
Mallards that avoided wetlands with large expanses of open\\ water had higher reproductive success & BloomEtAl2013 \\ 
American Redstarts that occupied wet forest habitat in the\\ winter raised more offspring than conspecifics\\ occupying other habitats in the winter & NorrisEtAl2003 \\ 
Great Tits nesting in mature woodland produced larger\\ broods than conspecifics nesting in gardens and hedgerows & RiddingtonGosler1995 \\ 
Reduction in winter stubble has led to a reduction in Reed Bunting survival rate & PeachEtAl1999 \\ 
Fledgling Ovenbird survival increased with vegetation\\ structure & KingEtAl2006 \\ 
Daily nest survival of eight forest species was positively\\ related to nest distance from the forest edge and nest height & NewmarkEtAl2011 \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\end{tabular}
  \caption{Examples of the effects on habitat on individual fitness.} 
  \label{table_fitness} 
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The produces this:

[image]

In table 1, the lines disappear off the edges of the PDF. Therefore I have added `\\` to put text on new lines. But is there a way to automatically create a column width so that text wider than the column width will be put on a new line? Also I need the references moved a line up - see red annotation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The original problem: The long entry of the first column was split in two lines in two table rows. The entry of the second column was then put in the *second* row. Instead, you want it in the first row:

```
Start of long text ... & Reference \\
long text continued    & \\
```

However, this can be solved in a more elegant way with an `X` column of package `tabularx`, then the first column gets all the available space and the entry is broken across lines automatically, see the [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/250025/16967) of Zarko. The following example does not use `\raggedright`, because it seems that the column width is so large, that justified text should work without much trouble. Also I have indented the following lines to make it easier for the reader to find the next table row. Alternatively some vertical space can be added to separate the multi-line entries.

The next problem are the lines, which do not look too good; therefore the nicer lines of package `booktabs` are used.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \footnotesize
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\hangindent=1em\hangafter=1 }Xl}
    \toprule
    Example & Reference \\
    \midrule
    Northern Wheatears had higher reproductive success in higher vegetation
    height & ArltPart2007 \\
    Mallards that avoided wetlands with large expanses of open water had
    higher reproductive success & BloomEtAl2013 \\
    American Redstarts that occupied wet forest habitat in the winter raised
    more offspring than conspecifics occupying other habitats in the winter &
    NorrisEtAl2003 \\
    Great Tits nesting in mature woodland produced larger broods than
    conspecifics nesting in gardens and hedgerows & RiddingtonGosler1995 \\
    Reduction in winter stubble has led to a reduction in Reed Bunting
    survival rate & PeachEtAl1999 \\
    Fledgling Ovenbird survival increased with vegetation structure &
    KingEtAl2006 \\
    Daily nest survival of eight forest species was positively related to
    nest distance from the forest edge and nest height & NewmarkEtAl2011 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
  \caption{Examples of the effects on habitat on individual fitness.}
  \label{table_fitness}
\end{table}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \footnotesize
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{Xl}
    \toprule
    Example & Reference \\
    \midrule
    Northern Wheatears had higher reproductive success in higher vegetation
    height & ArltPart2007 \\
    \addlinespace
    Mallards that avoided wetlands with large expanses of open water had
    higher reproductive success & BloomEtAl2013 \\
    \addlinespace
    American Redstarts that occupied wet forest habitat in the winter raised
    more offspring than conspecifics occupying other habitats in the winter &
    NorrisEtAl2003 \\
    \addlinespace
    Great Tits nesting in mature woodland produced larger broods than
    conspecifics nesting in gardens and hedgerows & RiddingtonGosler1995 \\
    \addlinespace
    Reduction in winter stubble has led to a reduction in Reed Bunting
    survival rate & PeachEtAl1999 \\
    \addlinespace
    Fledgling Ovenbird survival increased with vegetation structure &
    KingEtAl2006 \\
    \addlinespace
    Daily nest survival of eight forest species was positively related to
    nest distance from the forest edge and nest height & NewmarkEtAl2011 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
  \caption{Examples of the effects on habitat on individual fitness.}
  \label{table_fitness_addlinespace}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Your Table 2 has even solved my next problem - line spaces. Many thanks!

Comment: The `\hangindent` macro is really nice; I didn't knew about that. `:)`

Comment: @SvendTveskæg It's a primitive command/dimen register similar to `\parindent`, but its effect is limited to one paragraph like `\looseness`.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Exxxxxxcellent (to quote Mr. Burns)!

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    \newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}


\begin{document}
\title{}
\author{}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\section{Header}

\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering
    \footnotesize
\begin{tabularx}{\hsize}{@{}Ll@{}}
    \hline\hline
Example & Reference \\
    \hline
Northern Wheatears had higher reproductive success in higher vegetation height 
    & ArltPart2007 \\
Mallards that avoided wetlands with large expanses of open water had higher reproductive success 
    & BloomEtAl2013 \\
American Redstarts that occupied wet forest habitat in the winter raised more offspring than conspecifics occupying other habitats in the winter 
    & NorrisEtAl2003 \\
Great Tits nesting in mature woodland produced larger broods than conspecifics nesting in gardens and hedgerows 
    & RiddingtonGosler1995 \\
Reduction in winter stubble has led to a reduction in Reed Bunting survival rate
    & PeachEtAl1999 \\
Fledgling Ovenbird survival increased with vegetation structure 
    & KingEtAl2006 \\
Daily nest survival of eight forest species was positively related to nest distance from the forest edge and nest height 
    & NewmarkEtAl2011 \\
    \hline 
    \end{tabularx}
\caption{Examples of the effects on habitat on individual fitness.}
\label{table_fitness}
    \end{table}

\end{document}

\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering
\footnotesize
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}} lll}
\\[-1.8ex]\hline
\hline \\[-1.8ex]
Example & Reference \\\\[-1.8ex]
\cline{1-2}
\\[-1.8ex]
Northern Wheatears had higher reproductive success in higher vegetation height & ArltPart2007 \\
Mallards that avoided wetlands with large expanses of open water had higher reproductive success & BloomEtAl2013 \\
American Redstarts that occupied wet forest habitat in the winter raised more offspring than conspecifics occupying other habitats in the winter & NorrisEtAl2003 \\
Great Tits nesting in mature woodland produced larger broods than conspecifics nesting in gardens and hedgerows & RiddingtonGosler1995 \\
Reduction in winter stubble has led to a reduction in Reed Bunting survival rate & PeachEtAl1999 \\
Fledgling Ovenbird survival increased with vegetation structure & KingEtAl2006 \\
Daily nest survival of eight forest species was positively related to nest distance from the forest edge and nest height & NewmarkEtAl2011 \\
\hline \\[-1.8ex]
\end{tabular}
  \caption{Examples of the effects on habitat on individual fitness.}
  \label{table_fitness}
\end{table}
```

[image]

I add the `tabularx` package and define new column type `L` which allow multi line text in first table column. Similarly you can do with for first table.