# Horizontal alignment - two tabulars in minipages

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment

I originally had a list in `itemize` that I wanted on the left and a "legend" created by `tabular` I wanted on the bottom right of a slide in a presentation. Then, I learned that `wraptable` doesn't work with lists (`itemize`), so I changed my list to a table as well, and now I'm using `minipage`s to put the two tables left-right alignment. However, the alignment is vertical (top-bottom) and doesn't fit well. I realized if a `tabular` column has text that makes it wider, `minipage` doesn't seem to override that (I suspect). Does anyone have a clever way to get the legend "Clusters" on the bottom right? See code below.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{movie15, xcolor, multicol, amsmath, graphicx, subfigure, float, wrapfig}
\mode<presentation> {
  \usetheme{Warsaw}      
  \usecolortheme{beaver} 
  \usefonttheme{serif}  
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
} 
\def\clusterA{\hfill\rlap{\hspace{0cm}\textcolor{blue}{$\bigstar$}}}
\def\clusterB{\hfill\rlap{\hspace{0cm}\textcolor{red}{$\bigstar$}}}
\def\clusterC{\hfill\rlap{\hspace{0cm}\textcolor{green}{$\bigstar$}}}


\begin{frame}{DSM-5 Comorbidity Clusters}
\begin{minipage}{0.74\textwidth}
  \begin{tabular}{|r l l|}
    \clusterA & Neurodevelopmental Disorders (ID, ADHD, ASD) &  \\ 
    \clusterA & Schizophrenia Spectrum/Psychotic Disorders (SZ) & I \\ 
    \clusterB & Bipolar Disorders (I, II) & I\\ 
    \clusterB & Depressive Disorders (MDD) & I\\ 
    \clusterB & Anxiety Disorders (GAD, Phobias, Panic) & I \\ 
    \clusterB & Obsessive-Compulsive Disorders (OCD) & I \\ 
    \clusterB & Trauma \& Stress-Related Disorders (PTSD) & I \\ 
              & Dissociative Disorders (DID) & I \\ 
              & Somatic Symptom Disorders & III
  \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}{0.24\textwidth}
  \begin{table}[]
    \begin{tabular}{|c c|} \hline 
      \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Clusters} \\
      \hline
      \clusterA & A \\ 
      \clusterB & B \\ 
      \clusterC & C \\ 
      \hline 
    \end{tabular} 
  \end{table} 
\end{minipage}
\end{frame}
```

Note I've tried both `\textwidth` and `\linewidth` in the `minipage` options and it doesn't change anything. See picture below for current layout. Again, I want the Clusters legend on the bottom right 20% of the page and the first table flushed left to give room for the second table on the bottom right.

[[NOTE:: don't pay attention to the text in the tables - they may be inaccurate/they are my best guesses before research.]]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It doesn't really have anything to do with `minipage`, but that line breaking isn't enabled in the default column types for `tabular` (`r`, `c`, `l`).  One way around that is to switch to `tabularx`, and make the second column of type `X`, like in [Fix column width of table](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/250028). The second thing to consider is that a blank line is the same as a paragraph break, so your two tables would end up below one another even if there was room for both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can dispense with the `minipage`s; it's enough to use a `tabular` with `b` (botoom) alignment in which the central column is of paragraph type `p{<length>}` (thus allowing text wrapping) and not to leave blank lines between the `tabular` and the legend:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{movie15, multicol, float, wrapfig}
\usepackage{array}

\mode<presentation> {
  \usetheme{Warsaw}      
  \usecolortheme{beaver} 
  \usefonttheme{serif}  
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
} 
\def\clusterA{\hfill\rlap{\hspace{0cm}\textcolor{blue}{$\bigstar$}}}
\def\clusterB{\hfill\rlap{\hspace{0cm}\textcolor{red}{$\bigstar$}}}
\def\clusterC{\hfill\rlap{\hspace{0cm}\textcolor{green}{$\bigstar$}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{DSM-5 Comorbidity Clusters}

  \begin{tabular}[b]{|r >{\raggedright}p{6.5cm} l|}
    \clusterA & Neurodevelopmental Disorders (ID, ADHD, ASD) &  \\ 
    \clusterA & Schizophrenia Spectrum/Psychotic Disorders (SZ) & I \\ 
    \clusterB & Bipolar Disorders (I, II) & I\\ 
    \clusterB & Depressive Disorders (MDD) & I\\ 
    \clusterB & Anxiety Disorders (GAD, Phobias, Panic) & I \\ 
    \clusterB & Obsessive-Compulsive Disorders (OCD) & I \\ 
    \clusterB & Trauma \& Stress-Related Disorders (PTSD) & I \\ 
              & Dissociative Disorders (DID) & I \\ 
              & Somatic Symptom Disorders & III
  \end{tabular}\hfill
% <- important to preven ending the paragraph
    \begin{tabular}{|c c|} \hline 
      \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Clusters} \\
      \hline
      \clusterA & A \\ 
      \clusterB & B \\ 
      \clusterC & C \\ 
      \hline 
    \end{tabular} 
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Declaring bottom alignment for both `tabular`s:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{movie15, xcolor, multicol, amsmath, graphicx, subfigure, float, wrapfig}
\usepackage{array}

\mode<presentation> {
  \usetheme{Warsaw}      
  \usecolortheme{beaver} 
  \usefonttheme{serif}  
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
} 
\def\clusterA{\hfill\rlap{\hspace{0cm}\textcolor{blue}{$\bigstar$}}}
\def\clusterB{\hfill\rlap{\hspace{0cm}\textcolor{red}{$\bigstar$}}}
\def\clusterC{\hfill\rlap{\hspace{0cm}\textcolor{green}{$\bigstar$}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{DSM-5 Comorbidity Clusters}

  \begin{tabular}[b]{|r >{\raggedright}p{6.5cm} l|}
    \clusterA & Neurodevelopmental Disorders (ID, ADHD, ASD) &  \\ 
    \clusterA & Schizophrenia Spectrum/Psychotic Disorders (SZ) & I \\ 
    \clusterB & Bipolar Disorders (I, II) & I\\ 
    \clusterB & Depressive Disorders (MDD) & I\\ 
    \clusterB & Anxiety Disorders (GAD, Phobias, Panic) & I \\ 
    \clusterB & Obsessive-Compulsive Disorders (OCD) & I \\ 
    \clusterB & Trauma \& Stress-Related Disorders (PTSD) & I \\ 
              & Dissociative Disorders (DID) & I \\ 
              & Somatic Symptom Disorders & III
  \end{tabular}\hfill
% <- important to preven ending the paragraph
    \begin{tabular}[b]{|c c|} \hline 
      \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Clusters} \\
      \hline
      \clusterA & A \\ 
      \clusterB & B \\ 
      \clusterC & C \\ 
      \hline 
    \end{tabular} 
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As a side note, `amsmath`, `xcolor` and `graphicx` are automatically loaded by beamer; `subfigure` is obsolete, use `subfig` instead.

Comment: Thanks so much, Gonzalo! I had no idea about the "b" alignment option. A simple, elegant solution!